# What time period does 'until last week' include?

Tags: conjunctions, time, till-until

What time period does 'until last week' include?

In the following sentence - 'Here are the letters I recieved from John, until last week'. Would the list of letters also include the ones I recieved from John, last week?

Comment: No. "Until last week" explicitly excludes last week.

Comment: @Robusto would writing 'till last week' include last week?

Comment: No. "Till" means the same thing as "until."

Comment: @Robusto, thank you. How to phrase the sentence, so as to include last week as well (but not this week) ?

Comment: To be perfectly specific, try "Here are the letters I received from John prior to this week."

Comment: “Through last week” includes last week. But “last week” itself depends on context. If today is Monday, does “last week” end last Friday? Why not say “through the 20th, or whenever?

Comment: Despite these comments, it's likely that many people will be confused about whether last week is included. As @Xanne says, avoid vague terms like this and be precise.

Comment: @Barmar: My suggestion of "Here are the letters I received from John prior to this week" is perfectly precise.

Comment: "How to phrase the sentence, so as to include last week as well (but not this week)?" *These are the letters I received from John **up to and including** last week.*